# How many bytes does it take to store a single point in MSSQL server Geography type

Tags: sql-server, byte, storage, point, geography

I'm trying to compare the relative sizes of storing a lot of points as Geography type vs as two float types in a table.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a test, and added 100k points to a table that only has a Geogaphy type.  In the end, the whole un-indexed table was 3.6 MB big, so each row took about 36 bytes.  Compare this to 2 floats which take 8 bytes.

code:

```
CREATE TABLE Geog (  XY Geography)

DECLARE @i int  = 0; 
WHILE @i < 100000
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Geog (XY) VALUES ( geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.35900 47.65129)', 4326)) 

  SET @i = @i + 1; 
END
```

To see the table size:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME = 'Geog'    
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
```